# JSF initialization failure

Tags: java, jsf

While deploying an application on Weblogic 14c env, I am facing the below error and as a result JSF context is not utilized properly. Please find the stack trace below, apart from this no error is found in log. This is working perfectly fine in Weblogic 11g and it fails only when it is deployed on Weblogic 14c env

```
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,700 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <74 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Reading standard config org/apache/myfaces/resource/standard-faces-config.xml>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,714 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <88 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Reading config zip:/tools/appsw/oracle/apps/APPS_WEB_001/servers/APPS_WEB_001/tmp/_WL_user/vidreport-ear/51f6ex/war/WEB-INF/lib/ajaxanywhere-1.2.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,716 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <90 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Reading config zip:/tools/appsw/oracle/apps/APPS_WEB_001/servers/APPS_WEB_001/tmp/_WL_user/vidreport-ear/51f6ex/war/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-all-1.1.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,723 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <97 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Reading config zip:/tools/appsw/oracle/apps/APPS_WEB_001/servers/APPS_WEB_001/tmp/_WL_user/vidreport-ear/51f6ex/war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets-1.2.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,726 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <99 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Reading config /WEB-INF/c-facelets-config.xml>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,728 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <102 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Reading config /WEB-INF/v-faces-config.xml>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,732 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <106 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Reading config /WEB-INF/c-taglib-faces-config.xml>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,737 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <111 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator - Reading config /WEB-INF/ui_pagedefinitions.xml>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,740 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,755 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationFactoryImpl@1217d029 because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,801 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.RenderKitFactoryImpl@47e3482d because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?>
<Nov 24, 2021, 5:34:51,878 PM Greenwich Mean Time> <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactoryImpl@4263aebb because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?>
```

Comment: any help in thus regard is really helpful

Comment: Hey Manoj, It's been a while since I last worked with JSF but one piece of advice I can give you based on above logs is that your application is not starting because either wrong libraries or missing libraries (jar files, dependencies) on the 14c server, so go to your 11G version and check the server library folder to compare what is different with the 14c. I use to have the same problem with JBoss/Wildfly back then.